# Meting participant limits for Google Workspace Individual Subscribers

Tags: google-workspace, google-meet

In Google Meet, what are the meeting limits with a Google Workspace Individual subscription?

I don't see any information on the site other than *"Conduct group meetings longer than 60 minutes using a computer."*